# php delete query doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a delete function starting from this link

```
 <a href="videogamedatabaseadduserlist.php?function=delete&IndEMail='.$_POST['IndEMail'].'&IdGame='.$row['IdGame'].'">Elimina<a>'.'<BR>'
```

and this is the php it should interact with

```
if ($_GET['function']== 'delete'){
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=videogamelist', 'root', 'root',array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
    $sql = "delete from lists where IndEmail = :IndEmail and IdGame = :IdGame";
    $res_prepare = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $res_prepare->bindParam(':IdGame',$_GET['IdGame']);
    $res_prepare->bindParam(':IndEmail',$_GET['IndEmail']);
    $a=$res_prepare->execute();
    echo "Gioco cancellato";
}
```

After many try and searching on this site i can't find the reason the query doesn't work.

Comment: What errors does it throw?

Comment: Check if have errors on queries `print_r($conn->errorInfo());`

Comment: did you try to select with the very same parameters in that code? just try to do it withing the same code.

Comment: your href's at fault here and what the POST array's and `$row` origins are.

Comment: the problem is in the IndEmail that i can't get neither using post from the form or using get

Comment: resolved, but the code is still the same

Answer (score 0):

i tested and it worked! if this doesn't work for you, check db or form

```
    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=videogamelist", 'root', 'root');
        $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);;


        $sql = "DELETE FROM lists WHERE IndEmail = :IndEmail AND IdGame = :IdGame";
        $res_prepare = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $res_prepare->bindParam(':IdGame', $_GET['IdGame'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $res_prepare->bindParam(':IndEmail',$_GET['IndEmail'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $res_prepare->execute();

            echo "Deleted";
    }

    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        }
```

not sure where `$row['IdGame']` is coming from so i'm using basic form just to test the code:

```
<form  name="delete" action="test.php" method="get">
 <input type="text" name="IdGame">
 <input type="text" name="IndEmail">
 <input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete" >
</form>
```